# How do I convert text file to UTF-8 ,"bcp ... queryout -cC65001..." doesn't work

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, bcp

I'm working on a store procedure(MSSQL 2016), trying to output a text file by using xp_cmdShell.

Here's a part of script:

```
declare @bcpstr varchar (1000);

set @bcpstr = ''

set @bcpstr = 'bcp "select * from [table_name]''" queryout ' + @file_path + 'headonly.txt -t , -cC 65001 -U' + @user+' -P' + @pwd+' -S '+ @server_name

Exec Master ..xp_cmdShell @bcpstr
```

But what I get is ANSI text file `headonly.txt`.

Any suggestions? Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the switches should be `-c -C65001`, not `-cC65001`.

Try again with

```
set @bcpstr = 
    'bcp '+
        '"select * from [table_name]" '+
        'queryout "'+@file_path+'headonly.txt" '+
        '-t, '+
        '-c '+
        '-C65001 '+
        '-U '+@user+' '+
        '-P '+@pwd+' '+
        '-S '+@server_name;
```

PS: I've added double quotes around the file path to accomodate for spaces in the path, otherwise your statement will fail.